# Image thumbnail not showing while sharing link on WhatsApp: OG Tag issue

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, seo, facebook-opengraph, whatsapp

I have placed OG Tags correctly on my website but thumbnail image is not loading when I share my website link on whatsapp. I checked all other answers on StackOverflow but nothing seems to work for me.

This happened after I changed the image directory to a /storage folder.

**Expected:**
[image]

**Actual (What it's showing right now):**
[image]

Eg URL is: https://www.oxygentimes.com/cpap-bipap/resmed-airsense-10-autoset-cpap

The og:tags look like the following:

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="ResMed AirSense 10 Autoset CPAP (2023) - with Cloud &amp; Tripack (Optional)">
<meta property="og:description" content="Buy Resmed Airsense 10 Autoset  CPAP Machine with Autoset algorithm, premium features like advanced event detection, Auto Ramp, Climate control and 3 year warranty">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.oxygentimes.com/storage/productlargeimages/Resmed-Airsense-10-Autoset1648186681.jpg">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.oxygentimes.com/cpap-bipap/resmed-airsense-10-autoset-cpap">
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem... og:image is correct, but thumbnail is not showing up when sharing the url on whatsapp. When I check the facebook debugger, the crawler can't find my og:image...
Image is less then 300 kb and 256px x 256 px.
`<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://*****/img/thumbnail.jpg"> <meta property="og:image:width" content="256"> <meta property="og:image:height" content="256"> <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34581538)